# Advanced Custom Fields Options Page Setup

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have been trying to create an options page with the advanced custom fields plugin and have added the following code to the theme level `functions.php` file:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    acf_add_options_page('General Info');
}
```

However, when I refresh the wordpress admin panel, a link to the new menu option isn't created.

Does anyone know why this is and how to resolve? I am on Wordpress 4.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use the [associative array version of the function call](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_page/#parameters) so you can specify a `page_title` *as well* as `menu_title` :

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    $args = array(
          'page_title' => 'General Info',
          'menu_title' => 'General Info',
          'icon_url' => 'dashicons-schedule'
          //other args
      );
    acf_add_options_page($args);

}
```

Per usual sanity checking, you might also check  that the `advanced-custom-fields-pro` plugin is indeed active. Also, there's a note in that documentation page reading "This function requires at least ACF PRO version 5.0.0." So options pages may not work on [the non-pro version](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), if that's related.